# Facebook blocking test accounts

Tags: facebook, testing

I'm doing testing with Facebook and Facebook apps and have run into an issue with the test accounts. When I create a test account (under the app roles) and begin testing the app and the account, it keeps getting banned. To test my app and get all the information I need, I need to upload a bunch of albums to FB, but this keeps causing the account to get blocked. I was under the impression that the whole point of Facebook Test Accounts was that they were cloistered from the rest of FB and were exempt from odd behavior and being blocked. Has anybody else experienced this before? Is there a way to keep my test accounts from getting blocked so that I can actually do the testing I need to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

We have succefully used a bunch of FB accounts for manual and automated testing. Make sure that test users are under your test app. If you think that everything is done in right way, try to contact FB support team for help.